# Can anyone teach Xml layout for below image

Tags: android

[image]

Can any one teach me how to put above screenshot layout in android studio xml.?

Comment: use GridView to make this layout sharp and fast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/scrollView2" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="150dp"
                        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                        android:background="@drawable/pd5"/>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="120dp"
                            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:background="@drawable/pd2"
                            android:layout_margin="5dp" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="120dp"
                            android:id="@+id/imageView5"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:background="@drawable/pd3"
                            android:layout_margin="5dp" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="120dp"
                            android:id="@+id/imageView6"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:background="@drawable/pd2"
                            android:layout_margin="5dp" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="120dp"
                            android:id="@+id/imageView7"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:background="@drawable/pd3"
                            android:layout_margin="5dp" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="120dp"
                            android:id="@+id/imageView8"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:background="@drawable/pd2"
                            android:layout_margin="5dp" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="120dp"
                            android:id="@+id/imageView9"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:background="@drawable/pd3"
                            android:layout_margin="5dp" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

it is helpfull for u.

Comment: Thanks a lot ............

Comment: can you please tell me the main_activity .class coding for above xml code.

Answer (score 1):

use this concept

`Linear Layout` is parent layout with `orientation="vertical"` ......

Inside `Linear` layout `ImageView` and `GridView` .......

and use `custom adapter` for your `GridView` .....

have look of this its same like your problem [Image and Text GridView](https://www.caveofprogramming.com/guest-posts/custom-gridview-with-imageview-and-textview-in-android.html)

that is all ........

enjoy coding ........